# React Redux dynamic module loading module with promise instated of state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-dynamic-modules

Technology stack

- React, React-DOM - 16.11.0
- Redux - 4.0.4
- React-redux - 7.1.1
- redux-dynamic-modules - 5.1.1

I am trying to load reducers dynamically with the help of [Redux-Dynamic-Module](https://redux-dynamic-modules.js.org/#/) library and in sample code I did achieve dynamically loading. but while using connect function getting promise instead of state object.

```
const mapStateToProps = (store: any) => {
    return { products: store.productOptions }    <-- here I'm getting store.productOption as Promise
};


const ProductOptionsWrapper: any = connect<any, any, any, any>(
  mapStateToProps,
  {}
)(ProductOptionComponent);
```

Did try `await` to resolve Promise

```
const mapStateToProps = async (store: any) => {
  let data = store.productOptions;
  data = await data.then((r: any) => r);
  return { product: data };
};
```

but getting below error and not getting state.

> mapStateToProps() in Connect(ProductOptionComponent) must return a
>   plain object. Instead received [object Promise].

and also I'm not able to update store due to in store the data is stored as Promise.

So I need help how to properly use redux-dynamic-module with redux-connect.

> Note:- Also using reux-thunk middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a lot it was a typo kind of silly mistake.

I used `async reducer function` for `async` calls (just POC of an alternative way of redux-thunk).

```
export async function rootReducer(){ ... }
```

after removing `async` it's working as expected.